# Radio Streaming Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm interested in radio streaming for windows phone, .pls files to be exact. I tried the following methods :

1)pass the pls url to the windows media player :

`MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();`
`mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(@"http://.....pls", UriKind.Absolute);`
`mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;`
`mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;`
`mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();`

2) Smooth Streaming

Note that I'm using the emulator and i also tried the stream url from the pls( opened it in notepad and tried all the urls )

I've also read that one solution was to read the continuous stream, pass it to a media stream source and to a media element. Has anyone tried this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: And what happened when you tried those methods? Did you get some exception? What didn't work?

Comment: The media player said the it couldn't play the file and with smooth streaming nothing happend and when i checked the console 3 System.Xml.XmlException. When i've tried a continuous stream multiple parts of the SmoothStreamingMediaElement stopped working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your stream is [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (both by the phone and the emulator).
If not you'll need to manage (and possibly convert) the stream yourself.

I don know someone who has used the [ManagedMediaHelpers](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers) to play HLS audio streams on the phone but it is far from straight forward and unable to share examples - but it can be done.

Comment: Can he at least give me a tip or two? Even so, there are some pls files which led to a http://...:8080 site.  How the continuous stream can be obtained from these sites? Thanks for the reply!